# Not able to serve different robots.txt for CDN77

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cdn, genesis

We are trying to implement CDN77 in wordpress with genesis framework and want to serve different robots.txt for CDN. We used the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA} !^.*\.rsc.cdn77.org$ 
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots_cdn77.txt [L]
```

Our website is https://example.com and we have added a CND CNAME for https://cdn.example.com

We are facing the issue that our main robots.txt is getting rewritten alongwith the robots.txt for CDN website. Both robots.txt become same for above links. Both https://example.com/robots.txt and https://cdn.example.com/robots.txt serve the same resource.

How would I change the rewriterule such that each link serves their own robots.txt instead?

Comment: The most common practice is to seperate origin-server and application server, like, you point cdn.example.com to origin.example.com instead of (www.)example.com.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to setup a rule in CDN configuration. Saying  for example when https://example.com/robots.txt is requested before it contacts origin server it append something like /cdn/robots.txt once the response in received from origin server, serve it as /robots.txt it self. This is possible in akamai CDN. Not sure which one are you using.

Comment: Good suggestion. It's even better to use a seperated (v)host for the origin, instead of only a seperated directory (/cdn). So you can serve robots.txt and headers seperated, and you can use a cookieless-origin server easier.

Comment: seperate vhost you mean with different docroots ? else again both robots.txt will reside in same folder.

Comment: Yea one docroot for cdn, one docroot for no-cdn

Comment: instead of that i can tell you exactly how to do this in Akamai if you are using this for CDN. And i do not recommend to use different docroots. What if your site example.com is having some issue, how will you replicate  using origin domain? I personally do not recommend this. :)

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice you already mentioned you are using CDN77. I have expertise only in Akamai. If the suggestion that i mentioned is not possible in CDN77 then yes docroot is your answer.